# JQUERY/JSON, given a variable list of items, how to post to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, loops, each

I have a .each() that is running a loop to find the following below..

Given the following which builds during the .each loop

```
id - desc
313 - blah blah
213 - blah blah
313 - blah blah
323 - blah blah
```

How can I form this data in JQUERY to be posted to the server (coldfusion)

Comment: is that a literal string that's being built in the loop?  Or is it structured data (such as JSON - [{'id':'desc'},{'312':'blah blah'},etc,etc] to be sent to the server?

Comment: I'd like it to be structured data like a JSON object if that's the smart way to do it, bec it's going to be a record for each line in the database. But I've never done this before. Does that answer the q?

Comment: I posted my answer to your other similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436952/posting-static-variable-length-data-to-the-server-with-jquery-coldfusion

Comment: You're going to have to be  more clear in describing your situation to get a reasonable response.  "313 blah blah blah" is not a part of a clear statement of requirements. 

From your comment you said you are trying to post a record for a line in a database.  That's helpful. you should put that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've learned this can be done with JSON in javascript, which is a component for Coldfusion:

http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Look like a recordset in the browser. you can transform that as JSON , or you can try the javascript orm framework. like this:

```
 var ds = new JDataset();
  var ds = new JDataset();
  ds.append();
  ds.setVal("Id", 1);
  ds.setVal("Desc", "a");
  ds.apend();
  ds.setVal("Id", 2);
  ds.setVal("Desc", "bb");
  ......
  ds.post({url: "server/service.php"});
```

you can see more detail at http://codeboogie.com

Answer (score -1):

You can model a record in a database in json, by using the column name for each column value.

example:

```
{ "column1" : "value1",
  "column2" : "value2",
    ...
  "columnN" : "valueN" }
```

If you are sending multiple DB records in one json transmission, then put them into an array:

```
[ { "column1" : "valueA.1", "column2" : "valueA.2", ... "columnN" : "valueA.N" },  
  { "column1" : "valueB.1", "column2" : "valueB.2", ... "columnN" : "valueB.N" },  
   ...
  { "column1" : "valueC.1", "column2" : "valueC.2", ... "columnN" : "valueC.N" } ]
```

If you are sending other information, put the array into an object:

```
{  "messageId" : "ASDUO38748",
   "timestamp" : 1873873873873, 
   "records":
    [ { "column1" : "valueA.1", ... "columnN" : "valueA.N" },  
      { "column1" : "valueB.1", ... "columnN" : "valueB.N" },  
       ...
      { "column1" : "valueC.1", ... "columnN" : "valueC.N" } ]
}
```